# How to create a pop up window without a new browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using this:

```
function logData(lid){
    var dataWindow = window.open("analyze.php?id="+id,"Log Analysis",
            "top=300,scrollbars=yes, left=300, width=800 ,height=500");

}
```

But this is opening a new browser, and in a mobile covers the original site
(an unwanted behaviour).

I want to know if there is a way to create a small window without 
starting a new browser using JavaScript and jquery?

Comment: Yes, look into using "modal" in the jQueryUI library or Bootstrap libraries for example.  There are 100's

Comment: yah try jquery, there are many interesting stuffs you can use :)

Comment: Try to look into fancybox and lightbox evolution. Bot are great plugins and work really well.

Answer (score 2):

The most ridiculously basic one:

```js
window.onload=function(){

 document.body.onclick = function(e){

  if(e.target && e.target.tagName === 'A')
  {
   var skip = {
     '_blank':1,
     '_top':1,
     '_self':1,
     '_parent':1,
     '':1
    },
    elem = e.target;
   
   if(!skip[elem.target])
   {
    
    var possible_iframes = document.getElementsByName(elem.target);
    
    for(var i = 0, l = possible_iframes.length; i<l; i++)
    {
     if(possible_iframes[i].tagName === 'IFRAME')
     {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      possible_iframes[i].parentNode.style.display = 'block';
      possible_iframes[i].src = elem.href;
      
      var possible_close = possible_iframes[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName('a');
      
      for(var j = 0, k = possible_close.length; j<k; j++)
      {
       if( possible_close[j].tagName === 'A' && possible_close[j].className.search(/\s*close\s*/) > -1 )
       {
        possible_close[j].onclick = function(){
         this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
        };
        break;
       }
       
      }
      
      return true;
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
};
```

```css
html,body{width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}


.popup {
  display:none;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}

.popup iframe{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
  width:70%;
  height:75%;
}

.popup a.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12.5%;
  left: 85%;
  z-index: 4;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup"><a class="close" href="#">&times;</a><iframe id="popup" name="popup"></iframe></div>

<a href="404.html" target="popup" id="test">test</a>
```

This is not the perfect solution, since the `href` for each element must be set **before** the click.
But, if you generate the links on server-side, this will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You may user *iframe* for this.

```
<iframe id="frame" src="" style="display:none" ></iframe>
```

javascript:

```
function logData(lid){
 var frame = $("frame");
 frame.src= "analyze.php?id="+id;
 frame.style.display = "block"
}
```

Using necessary css styles make it appear like a popup.